# Modification of collections.Counter/Dictionary (to not store negative values)

Tags: python

I found the Counter datatype from the collections module and it is almost perfect for my
usecase. However I would like to implement a "simple" modification so it does not accept negative values and raises an error instead.

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter({"a": 1})
c.update({"a": -2})    # this should raise an error since c[a] = -1

d = Counter({"b": -5})    # this should raise an error aswell
```

Of course I could just write a function to check all values and call it after each interaction with the counter, but this sounds like a bad idea to me.

If this is too much of a "do not ask others for code" question i apologize. I would be quite happy about specific info about the implementation of "Counter" aswell.

**EDIT: I think an example with a standard dictionary would be perfectly fine.  So the question would boil down to "How can i make a dictionary which raises an error if a value is a negative integer?"**

Comment: More info about your use case would help.  In what ways are you interacting with the `Counter`?  It looks like you're just treating it like a normal `dict` (which is permissible but unusual), but is that just for the purposes of this example?

Comment: I think if you use the `Counter` object the intended way, there wouldn't be any negative values added, right? I might be completely off about that though.

Comment: @Samwise I only want to use integers as values and the default value of 0 when searching for a nonexistant key is great. However i think you got a point. Maybe i am too specific with this collections.Counter example. So a regular dictionary (which doesnt accept negative integers as values) would work aswell.

Comment: You need to decide whether what you want is `Counter` or a `dict`-like — they're not interchangeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this by just subclassing `dict` rather than `Counter`, since it gives you fewer methods to override:

```
>>> class PositiveDict(dict):
...     __slots__ = ()
...     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
...         if any(v < 0 for v in self.values()):
...             raise ValueError("no negatives allowed!")
...     def __getitem__(self, key):
...         return self.get(key, 0)
...     def __setitem__(self, key, val):
...         if val < 0:
...             raise ValueError("no negatives allowed!")
...         super().__setitem__(key, val)
...     def update(self, other):
...         if any(v < 0 for v in other.values()):
...             raise ValueError("no negatives allowed!")
...         super().update(other)
...
>>> d = PositiveDict({"a": 1})
>>> d["a"] -= 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in __setitem__
ValueError: no negatives allowed!
>>> d.update({"a": -2})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 15, in update
ValueError: no negatives allowed!
>>> d["a"] += 1
>>> d["a"]
2
>>> d["b"]
0
```

Note that the `__getitem__` implementation gives you the default value that you wanted from Counter.  Everything else works by checking for a negative either before or after calling the `super()` version of the method.

Comment: This does basically everything i wanted. Thank you very much!

Comment: You might even be able to then extend this behavior to the `Counter` methods by doing some kind of `class PositiveCounter(PositiveDict, Counter)` multiple inheritance sorcery, since presumably the `Counter` methods are implemented in terms of `dict` methods.  Multiple inheritance gives me a headache though so I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subclass of counter

Here I give you a starting point

```py
from collections import Counter
class PositiveCounter(Counter):
  def __setitem__(self, *args):
    try:
      k,v = args;
    except:
      pass
    finally:  
      if v < 0:
        raise ValueError(f'Attempt to set a negative value ({v}) to key {k}')
    Counter.__setitem__(self, *args)
```

And your update your example code to

```py
c = PositiveCounter({"a": 1})
c.update({"a": -2})    # this should raise an error since c[a] = -1

d = PositiveCounter({"b": -5})    # this should raise an error aswell
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt work. The second line does raise an error due to the negative value. However if i use `c.subtract({"a": 9})` it still goes to negative values. I think i have made this uneccessary complicated with the Counter example.

Comment: Bob: Python doesn't require `;` at the end of lines. Also I strongly suggest you read and start following the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines.

Comment: @martineau Appologies about the use of `;`, I am use to work with languages that do required, and in those languages I use indentation, even though they are not required hehe. Edited out the last one

Comment: @MartinDoleschal I updated the answer, to catch negatives in `__setitem__`, of course you can do your own class, I am only showing one way.

Comment: Also note that a "bare" `except:`, especially one followed by a `pass` is a very poor programming practice, since it hides all errors including intentional calls to `sys.exit()`). Generally speaking they should almost always be specify something, even if it's just `Exception` (and at a minimum print out what the error was).